# Remove a column from a dataframe where two conditions are true at the same time

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have dozens of files of survey data. Each one has several columns with numerical data, and then some columns with character data. I need to remove one column from each one, dynamically, based on two criteria which must BOTH be met:

- The column is numeric, AND...
- The column contains the word "Overall"

I cannot simply deselect any/all columns containing the word "Overall", because one of the character columns I must retain has "Overall" in its title.

I cannot simply deselect it by name or position, because the different files are not consistent with regard to position or name. The only thing they have in common is that the column is numeric *and* has "Overall" in its title. Also, not all files have such a column, which is why I am trying to do it dynamically.

Here is a very simplified example of one such file, as it appears in a dataframe:

```
#### reproducible example ####

columns <- c("rating A", "rating B", "Student Overall Rating", 
              "feedback 1", "feedback 2", "Student Overall Feedback")
c1 <- c(4, 4, 3)
c2 <- c(5, 4, 4)
c3 <- c(4.5, 4, 3.5)
c4 <- c("blah", "blah", "blah")
c5 <- c("blah", "blah", "blah")
c6 <- c("blahblah", "blahblah", "blahblah")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6))
names(df) <- columns
df$`rating A` <- as.numeric(df$`rating A`)
df$`rating B` <- as.numeric(df$`rating B`)
df$`Student Overall Rating` <- as.numeric(df$`Student Overall Rating`)

str(df)  # shows relative structure I am dealing with
```

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ rating A                : num  4 4 3
 $ rating B                : num  5 4 4
 $ Student Overall Rating  : num  4.5 4 3.5
 $ feedback 1              : chr  "blah" "blah" "blah"
 $ feedback 2              : chr  "blah" "blah" "blah"
 $ Student Overall Feedback: chr  "blahblah" "blahblah" "blahblah"
```

I have performed extensive searching and have tried a few things:

```
df <- df %>% select(!intersect(is.numeric(df), df %like% "Overall"))
```

which gives me:

```
Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns with `intersect(is.numeric(df), df %like% "Overall")`.
✖ `intersect(is.numeric(df), df %like% "Overall")` must be numeric or character, not `FALSE`.
```

I have also tried...

```
df <- df %>% select(!where(is.numeric | contains("Overall")))
```

which results in:

```
Error in `select()`:
! Problem while evaluating `where(is.numeric | contains("Overall"))`.
Caused by error in `is.numeric | contains("Overall")`:
! operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

My desired result is this, for the files that have that numeric "Student Overall Rating" field:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ rating A                : num  4 4 3
 $ rating B                : num  5 4 4
 $ feedback 1              : chr  "blah" "blah" "blah"
 $ feedback 2              : chr  "blah" "blah" "blah"
 $ Student Overall Feedback: chr  "blahblah" "blahblah" "blahblah"
```

I know I can do `select(where())` to do either condition separately, but is there a way to give it two conditions to fulfill at once? Is there some other way to do this? I am really trying to avoid manually manipulating every single file.

Comment: As a side note, when you construct your sample data, the reason you have to go back and convert the columns like `df$\`rating A\` <- as.numeric(df$\`rating A\`)` is because you use `cbind`. `cbind` creates a matrix, which can only have one data type, so everything gets converted to character. If you change `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` to `data.frame()`, then you skip creating matrix and skip those bad conversions, which means you don't have to convert your data back to what it should be. You should generally avoid `as.data.frame(cbind())`, just use `data.frame()` instead.

Comment: And welcome to the site! Thanks for including a minimal, reproducible, and verifiable example and demonstrating plenty of effort! It's an exceptionally good first question!

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for the note on constructing my sample data - that was a quick & dirty thing and I had gotten frustrated with the main issue so I didn't do it in the most efficient way (clearly).  

Also, thank you for the kind words - I am often on the side of providing the troubleshooting, so when I need assistance, I strive to help others help me.

Comment: Yes, `as.data.frame(cbind())` is just an anti-pattern I see fairly often that sometimes causes issues, so I try to point it out when I see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close!

```
library(dplyr)
df |> select(!(where(is.numeric) & contains("Overall")))
#   rating A rating B feedback 1 feedback 2 Student Overall Feedback
# 1        4        5       blah       blah                 blahblah
# 2        4        4       blah       blah                 blahblah
# 3        3        4       blah       blah                 blahblah
```

---

Some explanations:

```
df <- df %>% select(!intersect(is.numeric(df), df %like% "Overall"))
```

The above fails because you are applying `is.numeric` to `df`, the data frame. A data frame is a `list`, which is not numeric, `is.numeric(df)` is `FALSE`. And similarly for `%like%`. You need to be working with the column names, not the data frame itself.

```
df <- df %>% select(!where(is.numeric | contains("Overall")))
```

This one is close, it uses `!where` like in my working solution. The issue here is that `where()` wants a function inside it. `is.numeric` is a function, but `is.numeric | contains("Overall")` is not a function. It also doesn't quite work to put `contains()` *inside* `where()`. `where()` will evaluate the function you give it on each column, one at a time. `contains()` expects to look at the names of a bunch of columns at once.

Comment: I thought I was close, but I just couldn't get there.  I had the right ideas but couldn't figure out how to execute them.  I will try it tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Your answer worked in my actual situation as well as the minimal example I provided.  Thank you very much!  I was indeed very close.